# Easier way to manage POP3 accounts on CentOS6

Tags: linux, email, imap, pop3

We are setting up a brand new CentOS6 (64bit) server. Our hosting company just made it online and now we are installing packages such as httpd, mysql, etc.

We have postfix running on the machine. What we want is to use this server as pop3 email address server where we will be setting up different domains for managing their pop3 accounts.

Is there an easy-to-use control panel for this or can you recommend a guide which explains how to setup postfix+dovecot (or any other pop3/imap system) for managing accounts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to go for some ready made and Automatic solution, which is much more stable and very mature now.

**iRedMail**

A ZERO COST, fully fledged, full-featured mail server solution. All components are free and open source softwares.
An open source project, released under GPLv2, hosted on BitBucket (moved from Google Code).
What iRedMail does
Install and configure mail server related BINARY packages automatically from repositories which officially provided by Linux/BSD distributions.

**Benefits**

ZERO COST. All components are free and open source softwares.
Fully fledged and full-featured.

Easy, fast deployment in LESS THAN 1 MINUTE. View YouTube Video to check how easy it is.
Works on both non-virtualized and virtualized boxes, e.g. VMware, Xen, KVM, OpenVZ, VirtualBox, with i386 and x86_64 support.

Full-featured web admin panel - iRedAdmin-Pro. Online demo is available. You can setup mail server manually with the same softwares as used in iRedMail, but you cannot find a suitable web-based admin panel like iRedAdmin-Pro.
Works on major Linux/BSD distributions

**Addition info**

Used major open source softwares:
Postfix: SMTP service
Dovecot: POP3, IMAP, Managesieve service
Apache: Web server
MySQL: Storing application data and/or mail accounts
OpenLDAP: Storing mail accounts
Amavisd, SpamAssassin, ClamAV: Anti-spam, anti-virus
Roundcube: Webmail
Awstats: Apache and Postfix log analyzer

http://www.iredmail.org/

Comment: This is the one I'm looking for. Thanks, setting it now.

Answer (score 0):

Never used it but [ISP Config](http://www.ispconfig.org/)  is very popular

You could also use [Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/) which is a great product but might be an overkill if it's just for couple of users.